# Python/Pandas Structuring/Indexing For Graph

Tags: python, indexing, data-structures

> 1. Trying to change a column, that consists only of a series name being repeated in each row, to its own column with respective values.
>
> > 2. Doing this in an effort to make plotting/graphing the data easier

**FROM**

```
[Country, Series(GDP), Time(2018)]

[US, GDP, 123432]
[UK, GDP, 4345]
[China, GDP, 5722]
[Russia, GDP, 57764]
etc...
```

**TO**

```
[Country, GDP(@2018)]

[US, 123432]
[UK, 4345]
[China, 5722]
[Russia, 57764]
etc...
```

> *I'm guessing it has to do with changing the index(?). I can get it indexed based on 'Country' as opposed to the default 0,1,2,3,etc., but is this the right thing to do for later graphing purposes?*

*Further inquiry:*

*The actual dataset consists of apprx. 80 countries, 70 series with their respective values (ex: GDP  120941, GNI  9717), and 30 years.*

Comment: In your original dataframe, is it formatted so [US, GDP, 123432] is one row across three columns, or one row across one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [['Country', 'Series(GDP)', 'Time(2018)'],
        ['US', 'GDP', 123432],
        ['UK', 'GDP', 4345],
        ['China', 'GDP', 5722],
        ['Russia', 'GDP', 57764]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

df.drop(['Series(GDP)'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.rename({'Time(2018)': 'GDP(@2018)'})
```

[image]

Save your newly formatted data with `df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, sep=',')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). List comprehensions are a fast, easy way to pluck out the data you want from this series (i.e. country name and gdp). Then, you can put these new lists called country and gdp back into a dataframe to view and graph.

You shouldn't need to change the index to Country, but I suppose that depends on what you're looking to do with the dataframe and how you're looking to graph it.

```py
import pandas as pd

#Original Data, all just lists in one column
data = [['US', 'GDP', 123432],['UK', 'GDP', 4345],['China', 'GDP', 5722],
        ['Russia', 'GDP', 57764]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_1': data})

#Pluck out countries and gdps from the lists using list comprehensions
country = [row[0] for row in df['Column_1']]
gdp = [row[2] for row in df['Column_1']]

#Create a new dataframe
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Country': country, 'GDP(@2018)': gdp})
display(df_new)
```